# Is there a better solution than dynamic_cast in that case?

Tags: c++, interface, multiple-inheritance, dynamic-cast

I'm trying to make platform independent code so I'm using OOP. For example, on Windows, Mac OS X, and Linux you can have windows, but on android you have views so I'm trying to abstract this.

I first made a class to represent a window or a view which I called view:

```
class View
{
public:
    virtual ~View()
    {}

    virtual void display() = 0;
    virtual void hide() = 0;
};
```

Now the problem is that on Android, there is no title for views while on Windows there are so I decided to create another class:

```
class NameableView : public View
{
public:
    virtual void setName(const std::string& name) 
};
```

And then finally implement the classes:

```
class WindowsView : public NameableView
{
    /* Windows implementation */
}

class AndroidView : public View
{
    /* Android implementation */
}
```

Then I need to make some code which sets the name for a view only if it is possible (if it inherits from the `NameableView` class).

So how can I solve this problem? I first thought about `dynamic_cast` but I often hear that having too much `dynamic_cast` is an indication of a design problem. I'm a beginner in C++ so maybe I didn't think the right way and I should change the whole design.

Comment: Make `setName` an implemented no-op function in `View`? It's not so much of an abstraction breaker to have it there.

Comment: *"I'm trying to make platform independent code so I'm using OOP. "* - That's a bad idea to begin with. The point of OOP, i.e. of **virtual functions**, is that you can choose and change the implementation of something while the application is running.

Comment: It is also a flawed idea to try and design some abstract "base concept" for wildly different GUI environments. A better design is to develop the GUIs independently from each other, each according their own system's needs, and make them use a common business-logic component or backend where applicable.

Answer (score 3):

> I'm trying to make platform independent code so I'm using OOP.

This is not an optimal approach - polymorphic hierarchies and `virtual` functions allow different concrete object types that inherit from the same interface to behave differently **at run-time**, but you know the platform you're going to target **at compile-time**.

What you should instead do is  use *static polymorphism* and CRTP to provide a common interface that every concrete per-platform implementation must satisfy.

```
template <typename TDerived>
struct View
{
    void display() { static_cast<TDerived&>(*this).display(); }
    void hide() { static_cast<TDerived&>(*this).hide(); }

    constexpr bool supportsSetView() const
    {
        return static_cast<TDerived&>(*this).supportsSetView();
    }
};
```

In the case of `setName`, you should provide a `supportsSetView` check on every platform that returns `true` at compile-time if the view can be named. Then you perform that check on the caller side and only invoke `setName` if the check passes.

Example usage:

```
#if defined(PLATFORM_ANDROID)
struct AndroidView 
{
    // ...
    constexpr bool supportsSetView() const { return false; }
};   

using MyView = View<AndroidView>;
#else if defined(PLATFORM_WINDOWS)
struct WindowsView 
{
    // ...
    constexpr bool supportsSetView() const { return true; }
    void setName(std::string x) { /* ... */ }
};

using MyView = View<WindowsView>;
#else
#error "Unsupported platform."
#endif
```

Caller side:

```
MyView currentView;

if constexpr(currentView.supportsSetView())
{
    currentView.setName("something");
}
```

As `if constexpr(...)`'s evaluation occurs at compile-time, the code will only call `setName` if it is supported by `MyView`.